# Complex network topology visualization

Tags: graphs

Right now, I am using [Dia Diagram Editor](http://dia-installer.de/) to draw combinations of network topologies and VMs like this one (descriptions blurred afterwards):

[image]

This software has a couple of bugs and missing features. For example, rotating text has some disadvantages, like the letters in DB not being filled with the background colour. The white lines appearing after exporting as png are annoying as well.
Also, I cannot attach connectors. So if I want to switch the order of the two VLANs, I'd have to reattach everything manually.

Microsoft Visio would be my obvious choice, but unfortunately we don't have licences for that and I'm not in a position to buy any. So the software would have to be free for commercial use. 
I've heard of Graphviz, but the examples I've seen so far have left me in doubt whether a diagram like this one is possible with that.

Do you know of any alternatives? Regarding OS, both Windows or Linux would be ok.